# Type 'Promise<any>' is missing the following properties

Tags: angular

I am using HttpClient and HttpResponse(think so not available in the package) from @angular/common/http to get a response from fiberbase in agular but there some type cast problem in mapping the response as i think response generates Observable as return type. Could any one suggest where i am getting wrong.

I am getting error at const recipes while assigning it which states("Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'Recipe[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more")

```
import { HttpClient,HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

```
getRecipes(){
        this.http.get('https://ng-recipe-book-cb551.firebaseio.com/recipes.json')
        .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                const recipes: Recipe[] = response.json();
                for(let recipe of recipes){
                    if(!recipe['ingredients']){
                        recipe['ingredients'] = [];
                    }
                }
                return recipes;
            }
        )
            .subscribe(
                (recipes: Recipe[]) => {
                    this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
                }
            );
    }
```

I am expected to get array of recipes from response.json

Comment: What version of angular is it? (in ng5+ you need to use pipe and add map in the pipe)

Comment: @reza i am using angular cli v 8.1.2

Comment: if you are using ng8, you don't need to do response.json at all

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this

```
export interface Recipe {

  description: string
  imagePath: string,
  ingredients: Array<{
    amount: number,
    name: string}>,
  name: string
}
```

```
   this.http.get<Array<Recipe>>('https://ng-recipe-book-cb551.firebaseio.com/recipes.json')
    .pipe(
      map(data => {
        return data.map((i: Recipe) => {

          if (i.ingredients == null) {
            i.ingredients = [];
          }

          return i;
        });
      })
```

See working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p8z36u)

Answer (score 1):

`response.json()` returns a Promise. Try using `JSON.parse(response)` instead which will parse your array into a useable form.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and your are using wrong type of interface of [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) which causes the error you are getting.

I suggest you read up on http-client from the **[docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)** to understand how `HttpClient` works. **The `HttpClient` parses your response to an object**, therefore you also won't need to use `response.json()`.

Also you should use pipeable operators. Check the import of `map` and change your code to:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

return this.http.get<Recipe[]>('...').pipe(
  map((response: Recipe[]) => {
    for (let recipe of response) {
      if (!recipe['ingredients']) {
        recipe['ingredients'] = [];
      }
     }
     return response;
    }
  )
)
```

Also I'm wondering about the use of firebase, if you are in fact using firebase in your project, I suggest you look into angularfire to use it "properly", we don't normally use http-requests for getting data from firebase.